# How to add "backtick" (`) with a Turkish keyboard as developers use it especially in JS?

Tags: keyboard, backticks

I am using a [Turkish keyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/keyboards/kbdtuq.html) and I couldn't find a way to add backticks.

Can you please help?

Comment: This question is too vague. It does not mention the OS or Device used.

Answer (score 3):

Just press <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> for backticks(`)

and press <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>ş</kbd> for ticks(´)

Comment: In some keyboard types, you may have to press the key combination twice because ticks and backticks can also be used for accented letters(diacritics). For example if you press backtick combination then the "a", it will result "à" (a grave).

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac keyboard, I press ( Option + A + , ).

First it makes this annotation æ, then it makes backtick `.

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac keyboard, simply ( Option + , ). It prints `.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem with an Indian keyboard. So I used to copy (back tick) in my clipboard and pinned it. Whenever I needed it I would easily use it. But now under the same clipboard there is a Symbols icon and in that I have all the symbols which are not present in keyboard.

[image: keyboard]

Comment: Are you answering with a solution or describing a different problem of your own which you want help with?